# Highstock chart export as PDF with image and text in title

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I implemented High Stock chart in my page. i need image in chart title and i successfully did that using below code..

```
title: {
 useHTML:true,
 text: img_src +'Title'';
}
```

Image is show in chart but when i try to export as pdf its only show me **title** in pdf file not image. I refer this example http://jsfiddle.net/sameekmishra/LHSey/188/ but its use **highcharts.js** and I have **highstock.js** .
 When i modified above fiddle example with **highstock.js** then above example also did not worked !

Here is same fiddle but with high stock js : https://jsfiddle.net/vukwbu1r/2/
   **Anyone have idea how I can export title with image in pdf export ?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[exporting.allowHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML)**

```
exporting: {
    allowHTML: true, // for title having html while exporting
},
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/LHSey/214/)**

[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/vukwbu1r/3/) with Highstock JS

Comment: Not worked !. `allowHTML` is work with highchart.js but if u try with highstock.js then it not worked.

Comment: See my updated answer and [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/vukwbu1r/3/) with Highstock JS

Comment: Thank u @Rohan. Your updated ans work !!. when I debug my code I found that I need to give live URL of image. I tried with local server URL and that's why image is not load in PDF. I don't know this is a main reason but by live image URL I solved my issue. Thank you so mush again for your comment

Comment: Welcome, this answer will give an option for those users who wants to export highcharts with HTML content.